# How to strictly forward VPN client's traffic to particular network

Tags: networking

[Please see Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxPN2.jpg)

Please suggest some elegant solution to configure Linux server which has wg0 virtual interface with a connected vpn client to it to:

1. Pass *all* kinds of traffic from client in wg0 to eth1 network;
2. Absolutely zero client's traffic must leak to interfaces other than eth1;
3. No traffic other than from wg0 must pass to eth1;
4. In case of link down/up on any of interfaces rules must not be broken.

May use any of Linux distro, Wireguard (preferred) or OpenVPN.

I tried to do it that way:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface wg0 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 2
sudo ip rule add iif wg0 table 2
```

it works, but has no protection from link down/up and traffic leaks.

P.S. Maybe some kind of bridging or a way to obtain virtual eth1 interface on client's linux machine can also be used to achieve the goal?

Thank you

Comment: You can have instead something like `-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT` (and one for the other way round, i.e. `-i eth1 -o wg0`; or a stateful rule). Note the default chain policy is `ACCEPT`, which means all traffics would be allowed anyway, unless you have a fallback `DROP` or `REJECT` rule, so either add that as well or change the chain policy of `FORWARD` to `DROP`, otherwise you won't get any "protection" you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what's already mentioned in Tom's comment/answer:

- You could add a second catch-all route with lower priority (higher metric):

  ```
  ip route add default unreachable metric 5000 table 2
  ```
- ...or a second rule (use the `pref ...` keyword to make sure the rules are in the correct order):

  ```
  ip rule add pref 500 iif wg0 table 2
  ip rule add pref 501 iif wg0 unreachable
  ```

  (In both routes and rules, you can alternatively use `prohibit` instead of `unreachable` to generate an ICMP "Administratively prohibited".)
- From what I've read, an even better solution would be to assign both wg0 and eth1 to [a VRF](https://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/working-with-linux-vrfs/) – but I've never used this myself:

  ```
  ip link add vrf2 type vrf table 2
  ip link set vrf2 up
  ip link set wg0 master vrf2
  ip link set eth1 master vrf2
  ip route add [something] vrf vrf2
  ```

  (See [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt) for more details.)
- Finally, you could create a *network namespace* and move both interfaces there – they will become completely invisible to the main namespace:

  ```
  ip netns add ns1
  ip link set wg0 netns ns1
  ip link set eth1 netns ns1
  ```

  Each network namespace has its own interfaces, its own routing tables, its own policy rules, and even its own iptables/nftables rulesets – you need to use `ip netns exec` or `nsenter` to manage them.

  (The main way for different namespaces to communicate directly would be through a pair of 'veth' interfaces, like the ones you have in containers – although tunnel and macvlan interfaces can also be moved into a namespace without breaking their parent relationship.)